# Questions about Type HE Matrix String Theory

Tags: string-theory, research-level, ads-cft, anti-de-sitter-spacetime, matrix-model

I was reading the heterotic string section of [this thesis desertation by Luboš Motl](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0109149.pdf), since I *think*  I now understand the Type IIA Matrix String Theory. The only thing I knew about Type HE Matrix Strings, however, was:

That It has a gauge-group of $O(N)$.

From the paper, I can see that the Type HE Matrix Strings, in order to be consistent, need some sort of "extra terms" (wrt the BFSS Lagrangian Density/SuperYM Lagrangian Density ) in order    to exist in 11-Dimensional spacetime.

Now,

- What is the intuition behind this; intuitively, why does the absence of these "extra terms" cause such problems in 11-Dimensional spacetime. Given the amount of intuition behind Type IIA Matrix Strings, I expect that there may be some intuition in Type HE Matrix Strings too ?
- Where does the new gauge group of $O(N)$ come from when the gauge group of BFSS itself, was $U(N)$ all along.

Comment: Dear Dimension10, too bad. I was convinced that much of the thesis was dedicated exactly to answering these questions of yours and a few similar questions. ;-)

Comment: @LubošMotl:       Actually, my question is mainly about the intuition; i.e., is there a similar, elegant intuition      for Type HE matrix strings, as there is for the Type IIA?      About the infinite $N$ being finite  $N$  being related to the  momentum being non - zero and finite, etc.